# How to find out what profile was used for building *.ipa file?

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning-profile

Is it possible and how to grab that information about profile just from existing *.ipa file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881126/how-to-tell-what-profile-signing-certificate-was-used-to-sign-ipa

Answer (score 142, accepted):

I can give you a direction in this, not sure if it'll actually help:

1. Change the extension of the `*.ipa` file to `*.zip`.
2. Un-archive this zip file.
3. The folder contains a `*.app` file. Open its package contents by right clicking it.
4. Inside, you'll find an `embedded.mobileprovision` file.

**EDIT-** Since Xcode 6 doesn't show the provisioning profile, I'll extend the answer to still see the details:

5. Change the extension of the `embedded.mobileprovision` to `embedded.txt` **or** just open it with any text editor of choice.
6. Inside, you'll find some binary data and a hash that contains the profile's details like `Entitlements`, `CreationDate`, `ExpirationDate`, `Name`, etc which will be sufficient to conclusively lead you to the provisioning profile used to create the `.ipa`.

Hope it'll help!

Comment: Do u know how we can achieve this programatically

Comment: Sorry mate, dunno! Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: :)... Just for curiosity I asked. I wanted this to achieve in iOS. and I think its impossible. Apple wont allow I think...

Comment: You can write a script on your windows/mac to go through these steps for sure. But I don't think it's possible for iPhone or even useful!

Comment: This answer is obsolete now ! whats the new way ?

Comment: can be done using php program. The whole process can be done.

Comment: Unless my app is weird, there's no 'hash' in the `embedded.mobileprovision` file anymore. Just a bunch of binary data. Using XCode 6.3.

Comment: @shmim Try opening the `embedded.mobileprovision` file with `TextEdit` or `TextMate`

Comment: I opened it with Sublime Text. It's just binary data.

Comment: @shmim That's odd ... try with mac's `TextEdit`

Comment: Once the .ipa is unzipped, locate the ```embedded.mobileprovision``` and list it's contents using: ```security cms -D -i embedded.mobileprovision```

Comment: the embedded.mobileprovision no longer exists in the ipa

Comment: here is the video tutorial i made to do extact same thing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ic9WuPnnBL4

Answer (score 36):

Use [Nomad](http://nomad-cli.com).

```
$ ipa info /path/to/app.ipa

+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| ApplicationIdentifierPrefix | DJ73OPSO53                                               |
| CreationDate                | 2014-03-26T02:53:00+00:00                                |
| Entitlements                | application-identifier: DJ73OPSO53.com.nomad.shenzhen    |
|                             | aps-environment: production                              |
|                             | get-task-allow: false                                    |
|                             | keychain-access-groups: ["DJ73OPSO53.*"]                 |
| CreationDate                | 2017-03-26T02:53:00+00:00                                |
| Name                        | Shenzhen                                                 |
| TeamIdentifier              | S6ZYP4L6TY                                               |
| TimeToLive                  | 172                                                      |
| UUID                        | P7602NR3-4D34-441N-B6C9-R79395PN1OO3                     |
| Version                     | 1                                                        |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I came here because nomad has been working great, but today has started crashing. . . other options not looking great though. Looks like I'll have to debug Nomad.

Comment: Fixed. Happy Ruby + Happy Nomad again.

Comment: install `gem install nomad-cli` - prefix with `sudo` if using system Ruby.

Comment: Using El Capitan upgraded from Yosemite I'm trying to install it but nothing happens. I get this folder created `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nomad-cli-0.0.2` but it is empty. Installed using system Ruby with command `sudo gem install -V nomad-cli`

Comment: As noted above, when updating MacOS, you may need to re-install the nomad-cli. This was my experience on MacOS High Sierra. Then I was back checking ipa files again.

Comment: Embedded mobile provisioning file not found in your_app.ipa that download from App Store

Answer (score 13):

Something like the following dumps an xml version of the provisioning profile:

```
unzip -p <ipafile>.ipa Payload/<myapp>.app/embedded.mobileprovision | security cms -D
```

Replace `<ipafile>` and `<myapp>` accordingly.  If you don't know what `<myapp>` should be, try:

```
unzip -l <ipafile>.ipa | grep mobileprovision
```

Comment: the embedded.mobileprovision no longer exists in the ipa

Answer (score 3):

Below are step for getting profile details from an IPA file :

1. Change the extension of `IPA` to `ZIP`. This will prompt an *alert whether to keep .ipa or use.zip*. Go with `Use .zip` option

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 1.5]

2. This will convert `IPA` to `ZIP` file

[image: Screenshot 2]

3. *Extract the ZIP file* by double click on it

[image: Screenshot 3]

4. This will create a folder with contents : *Payload, SwiftSupport and Symbols*

[image: Screenshot 4]

5. Goto *Payload* -> *App file*

[image: Screenshot 5]

6. Right click and ‘*Show Package Contents*’ for App file

[image: Screenshot 6]

7. This will show detailed content such as *codeSign, localised file, framework, provision files* etc of your app file

[image: Screenshot 7]

8. You can see provision profile details in **embedded.mobileprovision**. This file *can be read only in txt file format*. So *add an extension .txt* to file

[image: Screenshot 8]

9. Now open this file using *textEdit*. Now thoroughly go through this file **you can see provision profiles for the IPA**.

[image: Screenshot 9]

Comment: Step 8. Press spacebar on that file to open Quick Look.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Xcode organizer and click on the archives.You can see the list of archives you have made. Clicking on it will show you the details like date of creation, identifier etc.  You can find the profile you created for this by matching this identifier you got.

Comment: Not positive but I think that someone else's Xcode cannot produce this same information just from the .ipa.At least symbolication works this way.

Comment: Yeah, this will only work if the `.ipa` was made on the same machine as the one used to get the info