# Converting an iOS app installer(.ipa) to .deb

Tags: iphone, ios, ipa, deb

Is it possible to convert a .ipa installer into a .deb? I have jail broken my phone, and all the Cydia apps are installed with a .deb installer. All apps installed with .ipa s are classified as "User Applications" while .deb s are under "System Applcations". For some reason none of my User Applications work, and I was thinking if I could repackage those user applications into .deb s and install them as system applications. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: This [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222946/how-to-find-out-what-profile-was-used-for-building-ipa-file/10223230#10223230) might help...

Comment: Don't fix (convert package from one format to another) if it ain't broken. However [this script](https://github.com/rullinoiz/ipa2deb/blob/master/ipa2deb/usr/local/bin/ipa2deb) might convert from `.ipa` to `.deb` if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have created some scripts to build the proper package layout for .deb packages.  But, if you're starting from scratch, you might want to check out Theos, which is a tool used by a lot of jailbreak developers to create their packages.

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Getting_Started

Answer (score -1):

A .deb is a debian package file. It's fairly easy to create them, you just need to put the files you want to install on their respective paths and create the proper control files.

I recommend you google how to create deb packages, and how to extract them, then you get a deb from your device and extract it's files to use those control files as a template.

After that, I think it's a simple terminal command (in linux or your iPhone's SSH) to package your app into a deb.