# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova iOS build does not use build.json parameters

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am attempting to deploy a sample Cordova application to an iOS device using specific code signing and provisioning parameters in build.json. The certificates and provisioning profiles are already installed on the Mac containing the development tools. The iOS device is one that is used for our normal development testing. I am using Xcode version 7.2 under OS X 10.11.2, and Visual Studio 2015 update 1 on Windows 10. Also, the iOS deployment target is version 6.0.

The build is successful and executes on the iOS device. However, when I review the configuration of the Xcode project created on the Mac, the code signing and provisioning are not the ones I selected in the build.json file.

I am using Cordova CLI 5.4.0 and remotebuild 2.1.0

The folder where the xcode application is created is:
`/Users/{myAccount}/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/{currentBuildNumber}/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/{AppName}.xcodeproj`

Within the build.json ios/release section:
`"codeSignIdentity": "{CertificateName}"`
`"provisioningProfile": "{Profile-UUID}"`

Opening the Xcode project properties window, Build Settings tab, Code Signing section, shows the default code signing IDENTITY ("Don't Code Sign", "iOS Developer") and profile ("Automatic")

**NOTE:** text in braces, {}, are substitutes for the actual text.

Can anyone please tell me where I might look next.

Thank you!

Comment: Which versions of cordova and remotebuild are you using? With remotebuild 2.x, if there is a build.json in the project root the build should pick it up. Which folder are you reviewing? Which configuration is being used?

Comment: Hey there - I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova team at Microsoft. Right now, we're investigating ways to make it easier for developers to recover from remote build errors in VS. I’m hoping to chat with folks like you who have encountered issues with remote build and reached out to the community for troubleshooting. Customer feedback is the number one way we make product design decisions, so I’d love it if you could make time for a 20min phone call this week or next to talk about how you understand and overcome build issues. jomatthi [at] Microsoft [dot] com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept expecting to find the code signing certificate and provisioning profile in the Xcode project configuration files, and especially in "Build Settings" tab of the project.

As it turns out, the provisioning information is included in the resulting .ipa file via command line parameters in the remotebuild server process. I was able to confirm the provisioning profile was include in the .ipa file by following the instructions in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881126/how-to-tell-what-profile-signing-certificate-was-used-to-sign-ipa).