# where is the provisioning profile which's used to sign an AppStore IPA file

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa

I have downloaded an app from the AppStore and I need to see its provisioning profile which has been used to sign that IPA, following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881126/how-to-tell-what-profile-signing-certificate-was-used-to-sign-ipa) I couldn't find the mentioned `embedded.mobileprovision` file inside the IPA after showing its package contents.

Is there  a way to view or dump contents of the profile used to sign that IPA ?

Comment: "downloaded the ipa from AppStore", hm... Is it a testflight build?

Comment: App Store apps don't have a provisioning profile; They are signed by Apple so they don't need one.  The question you linked to is regarding enterprise builds, which do have a provisioning profile

Answer (score -1):

1. Change the extension of the *.ipa file to *.zip.
2. Un-archive this zip file.
3. Change the extension of the embedded.mobileprovision to embedded.txt or just open it with any text editor of choice.
4. This file will contain the profile's details like Entitlements, CreationDate, Name of the provisioning profile used in the *ipa