# iOS enterprise certificates and identifying which one was used

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to work out which enterprise certificate is used to sign which IPA.

I have two "iOS Distribution" certificates with the same expiration (great!).
I also have "iOS Distribution Managed" certificate.

I am the last developer to sign this IPA, the previous developers have since left the company before I took over. I am using xcode to automatically manage/sign the enterprise app.

I have a look at the keychain and I can see a distribution certificate in my macbook that matches the expiration when it automatically signs it, unfortunately there are two certificates with the same expiry in the apple developers account. So how to tell which one is really being used?

What is the "iOS Distribution managed" certificate, as the expiry does not match up with the one being used to sign the IPA.

Can I also find out which certificate was used to sign the IPA by running some scripts on the IPA?

I am trying to work out which certificates I can safely revoke. So as far as I can tell the "iOS Distribution Managed" certificate is not being used to sign the app. Instead it is one of the "iOS distribution" certificates, but they both have the same expiry. So I need a better way to identify the certificate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tell what profile/signing certificate was used to sign .ipa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881126/how-to-tell-what-profile-signing-certificate-was-used-to-sign-ipa)